# Jest spyOn fails for React+Redux component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs

I'm trying to test that a function is called in the `componentDidMount` hook. I've tried two approaches to spyOn, but neither seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

**MyTest.js**

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import MyComponent from 'MyComponent'
const mockStore = configureStore([])
describe('<MyComponent />', () => {
    let store

    beforeEach(() => {
        store = mockStore({
            foo: 'bar'
        })
    })
    
    afterEach(() => {
       spy.mockClear()
    })
```

**Approach 1:**

This one gives the error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'myFunction' of null`

```
    it("function is called onMount", () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <MyComponent myProp={prop}/>
            </Provider>
        )
        spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'myFunction')
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    })
```

**Approach 2:**

This one gives the error:

`Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given`

```
    it("function is called onMount", () => {
        spy = jest.spyOn(MyComponent.prototype, 'myFunction')
        
        const wrapper = shallow(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <MyComponent myProp={prop}/>
            </Provider>
        )
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    })

})
```

**MyComponent.jsx**

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    this.myFunction()
    }

    async myFunction() {}
    
    render(){
        return(<div></div>)
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        foo: state.foo
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent)
```

Comment: It seems that for the 1st approach you have to add `wrapper.update();`. As for the 2nd case, the error tells you clearly that there is on `myFunction` method on `MyComponent` class

Comment: For your first approach the docs of [instance](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/instance.html) might help you, because `.instance()` returns `null` for stateless and functional components (on React 16+). And the error states "Cannot read property 'myFunction' of null", meaning it tries to do something `<null>.myFunction`.

Comment: @rostylav I updated my code with how my Component looks. myFunction is definitely in the class, but would it somehow not see it in this case?

Comment: Also [the example](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-redux) of the react testing-library might be of use for you. I am testing my redux components using a custom wrapper `render` function and not enzyme's `shallow`.